# Data from List<T> split into another List<T> with 2 nested List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have run into a bit of trouble with this linq query:

I have a list (`allStats`) filled with data (see `allItems` class)
the list contains several entries from different days which I need to break down so they are seperated by month and weeknumber like so:

```
    MonthNumber: 1,
    List<Weeks> Weeks:
        WeekNumber: 1,
        List<Days> Days:
            PunchedInLate: true,
            PunchedOutLate: false,
            PunchInDate: 2013-1-1 08:20:10,
            PunchOutDate: 2013-1-1 15:00:00
            PunchedInLate: true,
            PunchedOutLate: false,
            PunchInDate: 2013-1-2 08:20:10,
            PunchOutDate: 2013-1-2 15:00:00
            ...
            PunchedInLate: true,
            PunchedOutLate: false,
            PunchInDate: 2013-1-5 08:20:10,
            PunchOutDate: 2013-1-5 15:00:00
    MonthNumber: 1,
    List<Weeks> Weeks:
        WeekNumber: 2,
        List<Days> Days:
            PunchedInLate: true,
            PunchedOutLate: false,
            PunchInDate: 2013-1-10 08:20:10,
            PunchOutDate: 2013-1-10 15:00:00
            PunchedInLate: true,
            PunchedOutLate: false,
            PunchInDate: 2013-1-12 08:20:10,
            PunchOutDate: 2013-1-12 15:00:00
```

[PasteBin - Here you can download a sample program so you can run it from your machine](http://pastebin.com/sC09RaNb)

It is essentially an addon to the answer of this question that I am trying to create:
[SO - Splitting parts of a List into 2 List's and joining those 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275058/splitting-parts-of-a-listt-into-2-listts-and-joining-those-2)

> **EDIT:** I am sorry, I forgot to mention that I've tried the .ToList() method at the end instead of the cast at the start which produces this error:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TestClass.Weeks>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TestClass.Weeks>'`

```
public class allItems
{
    public DateTime PunchInDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime PunchOutDate { get; set; }
    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public int WeekNumber { get; set; }
    public int MonthNumber { get; set; }
    public bool PunchedInLate { get; set; }
    public bool PunchedOutLate { get; set; }
}
public class Months
{
    public int MonthNumber { get; set; }
    public List<Weeks> Weeks { get; set; }
}
public class Weeks
{
    public int WeekNumber { get; set; }
    public List<Days> Days { get; set; }
}
public class Days
{
    public bool PunchedInLate { get; set; }
    public bool PunchedOutLate { get; set; }
    public DateTime PunchInDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime PunchOutDate { get; set; }
    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; set; } 
}
```

And the code:

```
List<allItems> allStats = getAllStats(userId);
List<Months> stats = new List<Months>();
var asItems =
    from item in allStats
    group item by new { month = item.MonthNumber } into Month
    select new Months()
    {
        MonthNumber = Month.Key.month,
        Weeks = Month.Select(week =>
            from weeks in allStats
            group weeks by new { week = weeks.WeekNumber } into Week
            select new Weeks()
            {
                //WeekNumber = week.WeekNumber,
                WeekNumber = Week.Key.week, // I just noticed that I guess that I 
                                            // need this here, so I can group the 
                Days = Month.Select(days => // days correctly, right?
                    new Days()
                    {
                        PunchedInLate = days.PunchedInLate,
                        PunchedOutLate = days.PunchedOutLate,
                        DayOfWeek = days.DayOfWeek,
                        PunchInDate = days.PunchInDate,
                        PunchOutDate = days.PunchOutDate
                    }).ToList()
            }).ToList()
    };
List<Months> stat = asItems.ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your `Month.Select(...)` *doesn't* return a `List<Weeks>`. You can remove the cast and just use:

```
Week = Month.Select(week => 
    ... code as before ...
).ToList()
```

EDIT: Okay, I see what's still wrong. For each `week`, you're using a query which produces *multiple* `Weeks` objects. So this part:

```
from weeks in allStats
...
select new Weeks() { ... }
```

is of type `IEnumerable<Weeks>()` - and that's being used as the body of a projection in `Month.Select(week => ...)` so you've got a sequence of sequences. It's not clear how you want to turn that into a single list. For example, you could use:

```
Week = Month.Select(week => 
    ... code as before ...
).First().ToList()
```

or:

```
Week = Month.Select(week => 
    ... code as before ...
).SelectMany(x => x).ToList()
```

We simply don't know enough about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: 1 minute earlier and I would've got the credit for this one... Nice job, as usual! :D

Comment: I've updated the original question, I'd already tried that with no luck I'm afriad

Comment: @KasperMackenhauerJacobsen: No, by the looks of it you tried putting it after the *curly brace* at the end of `select new Weeks { ... }`, not after the bracket at the end of `.Select(...)`. If you still think you did it right, please post that *exact* code.

Comment: @KasperMackenhauerJacobsen: It's also *really* unhelpful that at one point in your query you have both `Week` and `week` as in-scope variables.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've updated the original code block as requested, that results in the error under the `edit` block. I'll see about coming up with an easier distinguishable variable name.

Comment: @KasperMackenhauerJacobsen: Well you've now got *one* code block, but you're talking about two different errors. Additionally, as you haven't shown what `allItems` (odd type name) consists of, we can't easily compile and test this for ourselves. It would be helpful if you could produce a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've uploaded the entire class file here: [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/CKL7AJhE) - `allItems` is essentially all of the above classes boiled into one. Hope this helps

Comment: @KasperMackenhauerJacobsen: It doesn't help nearly as much as cutting down on your complicated query one piece at a time until you've *either* got a simple short but complete program *or* you've worked out what's wrong...

Comment: @KasperMackenhauerJacobsen: And your pastebin is still incomplete as we don't have the `genericMethods` class...

Comment: @KasperMackenhauerJacobsen: Okay, I now see what's wrong - see my edit. However, as we don't know what you're trying to achieve, we can't really say what you should do.

Comment: @JonSkeet Here's a revised [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/sC09RaNb) you can run on your computer. Let me rephrase what I am trying to do, I can understand it might be a bit murky from my explanation. I'll edit the original question with the rephrased question.

Comment: @JonSkeet The question has been rephrased, should we move this to chat?

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried the `SelectMany(x => x).ToList()` method and while that did not return an error, it did return the data 4 times and not grouped by month. 

The `First().ToList()` method returns the days grouped by weeks which are grouped by months which is is what it is supposed to, but it returns 2 weeks lists with the same data in, so it doesn't seperate the weeks into the correct months. That must be something with the query though.

Comment: @KasperMackenhauerJacobsen: The problem is that your query is extremely complicated, and you haven't really explained either your data model or what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25977/discussion-between-kasper-mackenhauer-jacobsen-and-jon-skeet)

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you have an issue where you're casting:

```
List<allItems> allStats = getAllStats(userId);
List<Months> stats = new List<Months>();
var asItems =
    from item in allStats
    group item by new { month = item.MonthNumber } into Month
    select new Months()
    {
        MonthNumber = Month.Key.month,
        Weeks = Month.Select(week => //Don't cast here, put a ToList() at the end.
            from weeks in allStats
            group weeks by new { week = weeks.WeekNumber } into Week
            select new Weeks()
            {
                WeekNumber = week.WeekNumber,
                Days = Month.Select(days =>
                    new Days()
                    {
                        PunchedInLate = days.PunchedInLate,
                        PunchedOutLate = days.PunchedOutLate,
                        DayOfWeek = days.DayOfWeek,
                        PunchInDate = days.PunchInDate,
                        PunchOutDate = days.PunchOutDate
                    }).ToList()
            }).ToList(); //*** ToList() added here ***
    };
List<Months> stat = asItems.ToList();
```

Comment: I've updated the original question, I'd already tried that with no luck I'm afriad

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a `ToList` after yout 'Months' select:

```
List<allItems> allStats = getAllStats(userId);
List<Months> stats = new List<Months>();
var asItems =
    from item in allStats
    group item by new { month = item.MonthNumber } into Month
    select new Months()
    {
        MonthNumber = Month.Key.month,
        Weeks = Month.Select(week =>
            from weeks in allStats
            group weeks by new { week = weeks.WeekNumber } into Week
            select new Weeks()
            {
                WeekNumber = week.WeekNumber,
                Days = Month.Select(days =>
                    new Days()
                    {
                        PunchedInLate = days.PunchedInLate,
                        PunchedOutLate = days.PunchedOutLate,
                        DayOfWeek = days.DayOfWeek,
                        PunchInDate = days.PunchInDate,
                        PunchOutDate = days.PunchOutDate
                    }).ToList()
            }).ToList()     // <-- here
    };
List<Months> stat = asItems.ToList();
```

Note that you don't need a cast in that case either.

Comment: I've updated the original question, I'd already tried that with no luck I'm afriad